# Error when returning from jQuery Ajax call

Tags: web-services, jquery

I have this in my web service;

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello Worlds";
    }
}
```

And this as my jQuery;

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.support.cors = true;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:61614/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(0);
                alert(msg);
            }, error: function (a,b,c) { alert(c); }
        });
    });
```

When I run, my breakpoint in the web service fires and I return "Hello Worlds".

However, on return back to the jQuery I drop into the error function.  Safari simply alerts an empty string and IE alerts "No Transport".

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add `ScriptMethod` attribute:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello Worlds";
}
```

Also, you need to specify contentType in your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://localhost:61614/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            ...
```

Also, a good article on the topic: [Here](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/).

Comment: i added that descriptor but the problem still persists

Comment: If you go to `http://localhost:61614/Service1.asmx` in the browser and run your method from there, does it work? There might be some mis-configuration on the server side. I am using a bunch of web service methods like yours from client side (js) code without any problems with the exact code I showed you.

Comment: Also, go to the article I linked - in the bottom they have a complete downloadable solution, with server side and client side, see if it works in your environment; if it doesn't then it's a sign that something's wrong with your environment. Please update me on your progress.

Comment: thanks for taking the time.  Still not working.  I'm going to close this question I think and Open a new more relevant one as it's an issue across two applications. Seems this might be a x-domain issue.